# Eclipse, change compiler command (for JOMP)

Tags: java, eclipse, openmp

I want to use JOMP API (equivalent to OpenMP in C) but I met some problems:

This is the code I want to run:

```
import jomp.runtime.*;
public class Hello
{
    public static void main (String argv[])
    {
        int myid;
        //omp parallel private(myid)
        {
            myid = OMP.getThreadNum();
            System.out.println("Hello from " + myid);
        }
    }
}
```

It is just an hello worl but I have a problem with the compiler. Please have a quick look at this page to understand: 
http://www2.epcc.ed.ac.uk/computing/research_activities/jomp/download.html

But I can't, I do not understand how it works... I can only compile it with eclipse default compiler (I guess) and then I have only one thread!

I understand I have to compile this code (in a .jomp file) with 
     java jomp.compiler.Jomp MyFile
and then compile normally but I can't do this in ecplise neither in the terminal (I do not know how to install this compiler!)

ps: I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a Intel® Core™ i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the JOMP parameters to your launch configuration, this example can help you:

[JOMP eclipse workaround](http://www.lst.inf.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/ss10/24/assignments/assignment_10/eclipse.txt)

Comment: Tank you very much, it works! And you help was very clear! Thx very much!

Comment: mark the question as answered to help others who have the same problem

Comment: The accepted answer refers us to a now broken link.